# $\left( \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}, \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} \right)$ are roots of the equation $x^2 - bx + 3 = 0$. What is the value of $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If roots of the equation $x^2 - bx + 3 = 0$ are $\left( \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}, \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} \right)$, then what is the value of $b$ ?

$1)\pm2\sqrt6\qquad\qquad2)\pm2\sqrt3\qquad\qquad3)2\sqrt6\qquad\qquad4)2\sqrt3$

Here is my approach:

We have $\dfrac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^4-1}}=3$. Hence $\dfrac{r^4}{r^4-1}=9$ and $r^4=\dfrac98\Rightarrow r^2=\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt2}$. And $b$ is equal to sum of the roots:

$$b=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}+\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}=\frac{r(\sqrt{r^2+1}+\sqrt{r^2-1})}{\sqrt{r^4-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{r^4+r^2}+\sqrt{r^4-r^2}}{\sqrt{r^4-1}}$$
$$=2\sqrt2\times(\sqrt{\frac98+\frac{3\sqrt8}{8}}+\sqrt{\frac98-\frac{3\sqrt8}{8}})=\sqrt{9+3\sqrt8}+\sqrt{9-3\sqrt8}$$
We have $b^2=24$. So $b=\pm2\sqrt6$.

My question is, can we solve this problem with other approaches?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you need another approach?

Comment: @JitendraSingh The approach has lots of calculations and one may make some mistakes if not be so careful. So I'm looking for some elegant methods. And learning some new ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta $ be the roots of the equation with $\beta>\alpha$.
$${1\over\alpha^2}=1-\frac1{r^2}$$
$${1\over\beta^2}=1+\frac1{r^2}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{\beta^2}=2$$
$$\implies \alpha^2+\beta^2=18$$
$$\implies \alpha^2+\beta^2+2\alpha\beta=24$$
$$\implies b^2=24$$